# GIS data - Geoprocessing Service to receive data

Tags: python, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, services

I would like to move 8 shapefiles from one intranet to another intranet via arcgisserver (or an other method).  Creating a FTP site is not an option.  I think I saw somewhere on how to send data to a geoprocessing service.

Is this feasible?  Sending a shapefile to a geoprocessing service outside of the api with say python?  Thanks.

My basic need is to move 8 shapefiles from one intranet to another intranet.

Comment: Are you going to repeat the process after a few days? And If they are on separate Intranets, how can you access the same arcgisserver from both? And If you can access a common location of both locations, why not just share the data over the network? It all looks like an overkill to me

Comment: The process will probably be repeated every day for another year or so. Accessing the same ArcGIS server via the internet. The intranet that is the receiving end is on the same network as AGS. My question is how to move this data over to that receiving intranet without ftp from the other intranet. Can it be done with ArcGIS Server? Thanks. (my other option is to tell someone they have to go over to the computer and with a thumbdrive and copy the data and then walk it over to their desk). A computer on the sender intranet is in the office.

Comment: that is called sneaker-net. :) I used to manage one of those.

Comment: Does the fact that they are _shape_ files make them special?  If not, perhaps this question could better be asked as "How do I move files from one intranet to another?" on a site like [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer).

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Nope. I just didn't have an idea of where else to post the question aside from my local python user group. Thanks for the tip and I posted it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question some time ago. My answer then was to use rsync and I stick to that:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18126/3895

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to set up one-way replication (assuming the ags has ArcSDE running).
replicate from the sde database, to a filegdb on the other end.
Then run gp tools on both ends to ingest and output the shape files.
Just keep overwriting the featureclasses in the sde as you load the new shapefiles.
It does sound like overkill but if you gotta have shape and you gotta have em everyday.
[replication help from esri](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002700000024000000.htm)
[Geoprocessing tools overview](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_s_new_for_geoprocessing_in_ArcGIS_10/00qp0000000q000000/)
[Geoprocessing Tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00530000000m000000)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ArcGIS 10?  If so, you could read the features out of each shapefile and send those to the editing endpoints of a feature class on the other side.  Another way would be to use replication as mentioned earlier, but you will have to have the correct licensing and no shapefiles.  I really do not think this is the right tool for the job.  Thought about uploading them to ArcGIS.com as private and sharing with the other workgroup using your ESRI accounts.

Comment: ArcGIS 10/ArcGIS Server 10/ArcSDE on receiving intranet.  ArcMap 9.3 on sending intranet.  The data will be changing..how would I upload to ArcGIS.com programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could would write a [WCF Rest service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529) to which you could POST (upload) the file.

I suppose the python in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157568/upload-a-file-with-rest) would also work with a WCF based REST service.